# Why is object destructor not called when script terminates?

Tags: perl, signals, destroy

I have a test script like this:

```
package Test;
sub new { bless {} }
sub DESTROY { print "in DESTROY\n" }

package main;
my $t = new Test;
sleep 10;
```

The destructor is called after `sleep` returns (and before the program terminates). But it's not called if the script is terminated with Ctrl-C. Is it possible to have the destructor called in this case also?

Answer (score 7):

As Robert [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629023/why-is-object-destructor-not-called-when-script-terminates/2629030#2629030), you need a signal handler.
If all you need is the object destructor call, you can use this:

`$SIG{INT} = sub { die "caught SIGINT\n" };`.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to set up a signal handler.

```
package Test;
sub new { bless {} }
sub DESTROY { print "in DESTROY\n" }

package main;

my $terminate = 0;

$SIG{INT} = \&sigint;

sub sigint { $terminate = 1; }

my $t = new Test;

while (1) {
    last if $terminate;
    sleep 10;
}
```

Something along these lines.  Then in your main loop just check `$terminate` and if it's set exit the program normally.

What happens is that the cntl-c interrupts the sleep, the signal handler is called setting `$terminate`, sleep returns immediately, it loops to the top, tests `$terminate` and exits gracefully.